# Captcha image not loading after refresh button click

Tags: javascript, opencart, captcha, opencart-3

I am using Opencart V 3.0.3.0

On page reload, captcha image is displayed properly.

**But when click on 'Reload'**, script works/executed but captcha image is not loaded / displayed.

I am using following code :

```
<img src="index.php?route=tool/my_captcha" alt="" id='captchaimg'/> <br></br>
<a id="capreload" href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();">Reload</a>
          
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshCaptcha(){  
        //alert('Hi');
        d = new Date();
        $('#captchaimg').attr('src', 'index.php?route=tool/my_captcha/?'+d.getTime());

    //I tried as below too
 document.getElementById("captchaimg").src = 'index.php?route=tool/my_captcha/?'+d.getTime();
    }
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The path already has a `?` so the `tool/my_captcha/` part is a query string value. Instead of appending `?` at the end, try replacing it with a `&` so it's `.src = 'index.php?route=tool/my_captcha/&'+d.getTime()`

Comment: @cbr I tried with your solution. But till issue is same...

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools' (try F12) Network tab and see if the browser reloads the image when you click on the button, and if the request fails for some reason.

Comment: @cbr I checked in developer tool, src is getting change to index.php?route=tool/my_captcha/&42482484 (random code) but image is not getting displayed.. in Network, showing 404 error